# SSH Google Compute Engine down?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

There's an issue with SSH access today ?
Don't know why I can't access to my instances today, from a MobaXterm or the SSH webinterface in Google Cloud (impossible to connect port 22).

Global issue or only my account ?

Comment: Try the serial console via Google Cloud Shell.

Comment: Same error => ssh: connect to host XXXX port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: If you spin a new VM do you get the same error? Try running a [port scan](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html)  to one VM to see if you see the service filtered or being closed. Does the serial console show any errors in the VMs?
I would also test using [SSH from the browser](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser)

Answer (score 1):

My bad,
We are using an other server to access to the one I mentioned previously and with a restart of this server now the SSH access is good again.